# Tank with pumps - creating a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let's consider the following problem. Imagine there is a tank filled up water (it's volume is equal to $V$). We connect two pumps to out tank. The first one pumps into the tank a mixture of 10% alcohol and water ($s_1$ liter per minute). The second one pumps out of the tank what's inside (with the speed equal to $s_2$ liters per minute).

I am to find the function $x(t)$ which describes the concentration of alkohol in a tank at any given time $t$. Of course $x(0) = 0$.

I am a bit stuck here. How should the equation look like? How can I derive it?

Comment: My recommendation for all such problems is that you write down the (approximate) $\Delta x$ in a time interval $\Delta t$, and then divide and take the limit to obtain the differential equation. I find this approach far less confusing and widely applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to write a short and easy to read answer:

The amount of substance in water: $$x*V$$
The change rate of substance in water: $$(x*V)'$$
The change rate of water level: $$V' = s_1-s_2$$
The rate at which the substance is flowing into the tank is: $$0.1*s_1$$
The rate at which the substance is flowing out of the tank is: $$x*s_2$$

So you end up with ODEs:

$$(x*V)' = 0.1*s_1-x*s_2$$
$$V' = s_1-s_2$$

Need initial conditions for both $x$ and $V$.

Some other answers are incorrect. common pitfalls: $x$ is the concentration; $s_1$ is in general not $s_2$ so $V$ might not be constant.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the rate of change of alcohol in the tank.

The rate is foun by rate in minus rate out

Rate in is $$0.10s_1$$
Rate out is $$\frac {x(t)}{V(t)}s_2$$
Thus

$$x'(t)=0.10s_1-\frac {x(t)}{V(t)}s_2$$

Assuming that the volume stays constant the equation is easier to solve.